# Update loop in windows forms?

Tags: winforms

I've been working with some game engines lately. They all have an `Update()` function that gets called every frame (not a loop in the strict sense of the word, but you get the idea). Any code you want to execute needs to be placed in here.

This made me wonder, how does this work in windows forms, as the only thing I use there is events?

(If the title doesn't explain it good enough, feel free to change it)

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/12/06/when-winforms-met-game-loop.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically works the same, it is only called the message loop, event loop or message pump

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383738.aspx